# find command outputs nothing

Tags: linux, arch-linux, find

Recently, find command behavior is strange.

```
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createZipArchive.sh
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createImgArchive.sh
find: `/home/data/lost+found': Permission denied
find: `/home/music/lost+found': Permission denied
(snip)
```

I executed find but I got nothing and it exited within 1 second.
So, I did again. I got the right result this time.
(Permission denied is by NFS)

I use arch linux 64bit. the version of find is as follows:

```
[root@luna ~]# type -a find
find is /usr/bin/find
[root@luna ~]# find --version | head -1
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
[root@luna ~]#
```

Any help?

EDIT:

```
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
[root@luna ~]# echo $?
0
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createZipArchive.sh
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createImgArchive.sh
find: `/home/data/lost+found': Permission denied
^C
[root@luna ~]#
```

EDIT:

It seems to be reproducible once after reboot.

I have these two lines in /etc/fstab:

```
nicobo:/export/music    /home/music     nfs             vers=4.2,rw,soft,bg,intr,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10 0 0
nicobo:/export/data     /home/data      nfs             vers=4.2,rw,soft,bg,intr,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10 0 0
```

After I comment out these lines and reboot, it is not reproducible.
I uncommented, rebooted, and I got the follows:

```
[root@luna ~]# ls /home/data > /dev/null
[root@luna ~]# ls /home/music > /dev/null
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createZipArchive.sh
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createImgArchive.sh
find: `/home/data/lost+found': Permission denied
^C
[root@luna ~]#
```

And I can reproduce it:

```
[root@luna ~]# umount /home/data
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createZipArchive.sh
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createImgArchive.sh
find: `/home/data/lost+found': Permission denied
^C
[root@luna ~]# umount /home/data
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
[root@luna ~]# find / -name \*.sh -print
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createZipArchive.sh
/home/data/tools/rd/RDService/scripts/createImgArchive.sh
find: `/home/data/lost+found': Permission denied
^C
[root@luna ~]#
```

It seems to be an autofs-related issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome on Super User. I have the same version of `find` on another distribution.Mine is working as expected. Please run again `find / -name \*.sh -print` and when it exits, write `echo $?` to understand if it is crashed.

Comment: I too run the same `find` version on ArchLinux amd64. It works perfectly on my system.

Comment: So, it seems like the first time you run `find` the file-system is simply not mounted, but by the second time autofs has done its thing? If so, I think it's functioning as expected.

Comment: When the filesystem is not mounted and I accessed it, it should be mounted and accessible, I think. git version of findutils has been already fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be fixed with findutils 4.6.0 in arch linux.